# Given a Pandas DataFrame, how to find all rows that the value (string) is a part of a longer string? Is there a built-in function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For example, given a dataframe:

```
[['aaa'], 
 ['aab'], 
 ['aac'], 
 ['aad']]
```

And I want to find all cells whose value is a substring of a long string 'aaabbb'. The first and second should match.

For sure I can do this by doing a loop, but is there a built-in function that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example above is a list but I assume that is the output you want. Try the following:

```
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['aaa', 'baa', 'abc', 'cba', 'aac', 'aab']})

string = 'aa'
df['String'] = df['Data'].apply(lambda x: string in x)
print(df[df['String']]['Data'])
```

Comment: I just oversimplified the dataframe :) Thanks for the answer, it works, though I need to change it to 'x in string'.